# jQuery, trying to remove a hidden div after x seconds?

Tags: jquery, hide, settimeout

Hey there, I am trying to have a div "hide", then "remove" once the hide animation is finished. It seems I can get either to work, but not both. I have tried using the setTimeout, but this only results in the div getting hidden, but not actually removed.

Here is the code:

```
$(this).parents("div:eq(0)").hide("fast");
setTimeout(function () { $(this).parents("div:eq(0)").remove();}, 1000);
```

If I do the remove without the setTimeout, it removes the div, but does not display the hide animation.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's a scoping issue.  When your `setTimeout()` function runs, the context of `this` is different inside the function than what it was when you declared it.

Try this:

```
var self = $(this).parents("div:eq(0)");
self.hide("fast");
setTimeout(function () { self.remove();}, 1000);
```

Comment: why do the .parents leg work twice? Remember this traverses all parents

Comment: @redsquare - good call.  I was only paying attention to the scoping, not the actual selectors when I wrote it.  I updated it to be a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like:

```
$(this).parents("div:eq(0)").hide("fast", function(){
    var div = this;
    setTimeout(function () { $(div).remove(); }, 1000);
});
```

that will run the settimeout code when the hide code has finished.

more info here on the callback: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

--fixed for the scope of `this`

Answer (score 2):

Hey all, thanks for the awesome (and fast!) responses! Appreciate it.

I ended up using a combination of several of them that seems to work well.

```
$(this).closest("div").hide("fast", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

@John: Thanks! I'm fairly new to this, and keep forgetting about the callback (smacks hand to forehead!)

@redsqure: Thanks for the efficiency tip! Still learning...

@zombat: Yes, good catch - I got around it in the above with removing the call to the partents in the call back, as I was removing the parents's parent at that point. ;)

@Tim: The .delay(1000) looked promising, I couldn't get it to work(?) (yes, I'm using 1.4) ;)

Thanks ppl! :)

Answer (score 0):

.hide takes a complete callback that you could use. Also .closest is more efficent than the parents first that you are currently using.

```
var $div = $(this).closest('div');

$div.hide("fast", function(){
    $div.remove();
});
```

To use setTimeout you would do

```
var $div = $(this).closest('div');

$div.hide("fast");

window.setTimeout(function () { 
      $div.remove();
}, 1000);
```